# Support vs range of a random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Is there any difference between the two? I have not met any formal definition of the support of a random variable. I know that for the function $f$ the support is a closure of the set $\{y:\;y=f(x)\ne0\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The support of the probability distribution of a random variable $X$ is the set of all points whose every open neighborhood $N$ has the property that $\Pr(X\in N)>0$.

It is more accurate to speak of the support of the *distribution* than that of the support of the random variable.

The complement of the support is the union of all open sets $G$ such that $\Pr(X\in G)=0$.  Since the complement is a union of open sets, the complement is open.  Therefore the support is closed.

Comment: I see. It is often written "let $X$ be a random variable with support S", which confused me, since the random variable is also a function. Thank you for clarification!

Comment: Note that the support of the distribution of $X$ is the same as the [essential range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_range) of the measurable function $X$ itself.

Comment: What about measure theory? I believe the definition of the support of a function $f : A \rightarrow B $ is : {$x \in A : f(x) \neq 0$}, that is the same as the range of the function, right?

Comment: This doesn't distinguish between the two. Here the support is defined but the range is not defined. Would welcome a definition of range to clarify.