# Implications of assumptions on the distribution and support of a random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, absolute-continuity

Suppose that we have a random vector $V\equiv (V_1,..., V_M)$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ with support $\mathcal{V} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$ that is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^M$ with strictly positive Lebesgue measure. Moreover, $V$ has a  distribution absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on $\mathcal{V}$.

**Question 1:** Does this imply that the function 
$$
a\equiv (a_1,...,a_M)\in \mathbb{R}^M \mapsto H(a)\equiv  \begin{pmatrix}
P(V_1-V_k\geq a_k-a_1 \text{ }\forall k \neq 1)\\
...\\
P(V_M-V_k\geq a_k-a_1 \text{ }\forall k \neq M)\\
\end{pmatrix}\in [0,1]^M
$$
is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^M$?

**Question 2:** Let $\mathcal{V}=\mathbb{R}^M$. Does this imply that $H$ is continuous **AND** strictly increasing in each dimension?

---

**My thoughts:** I think that the answer to both is Yes because it comes from the properties of the cdf of $V$ that is continuous when $\mathcal{V}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^M$ and continuous and strictly increasing when $\mathcal{V}= \mathbb{R}^M$. But I still have doubts because we are dealing with differences between components of $V$.

Comment: Consider $M = 2$. If $(a_1^n, a_2^n) \rightarrow (a_1, a_2)$, then $1_{(V_1 + a_1^n > V_2 + a_2^n)}$ converges pointwisely to $1_{(V_1 + a_1 > V_2 + a_2)}$. Absolute continuity guarantees that you can use strict inequality to define $H$.

Comment: Thank you. So the answer is 1) Yes, 2) No?