# Finding the probability density function of a random variable in two dimensions

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y)$ be a point chosen at random from the triangle $\{x,y:0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}$. $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=2$ if $(x,y)$ is in the triangle, and it is 0 otherwise. Find the probability density function for $X$.

What confuses me about this problem is understanding how $x$ and $y$ make up the triangle. If I'm understanding this correctly, then the biggest triangle we can make has vertices $(0,1),(1,1),$ and $(0,0)$. If this is the case then the probability should be 1. As $x$ increases, $y$ can at least be $x$ which means that $y$ is dependent on $x$. From this though I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Note the marginal density property $f_X(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y\mid X=x)}$. You may find [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48304/how-to-find-marginal-distribution-from-joint-distribution-with-multi-variable-de) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I'm understanding this correctly, then the biggest triangle we can make has vertices $(0,1),(1,1),$ and $(0,0)$.

You're right, that's the [support](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846011/precise-definition-of-the-support-of-a-random-variable) of your random (multivariate) variable.

> If this is the case then the probability should be 1.

Huh... what? What you know is that "total" probability is $1$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy=1$.  Now, because the density here is constant, denoting by $S$ the support region and by $A_S$ its area we get
$\int_{S} 2 dx dy= 2 \, A_S= 1$ and this is indeed true, because the area of the triange is $\frac12$. Then, it's all right.

> As $x$ increases, $y$ can at least be $x$ which means that $y$ is dependent on $x$.

Yes. In fact, if you have a bounded support that it's not a rectangle, (or a cartesian product of rectangles) then the variables are dependent.

You have the joint density $f_{X,Y}$. To get the single variable ("marginal") density, you sum (integrate) over the other variable ("marginalize") :

$$ f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy $$

Because the density is constant, and the support is known, what remains is just to get the integrations limits right, i.e. which is the range for the integrating variable ($y$) for each fixed $x$. Can you go on from here?

Comment: I gave this a bit more thought. Would we be doing a double integral over the triangle? The first from 0 to $x$ then the second from $x$ to $y$?

Comment: No, the double integral is what gives 1. To marginalize you need only to integrate with respect to $y$, as I explained.

Comment: So is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ simply $(1-x)$ which means I take $\int_0^1(-x+1)dy$ to find $f_X(x)$? Sorry, this feels far beyond my skills in probability. I'm going to offer a bounty on this problem.

Comment: Using the last formula $$f_X(x)=\int_x^1 2dy = 2(1-x).$$

Comment: NB: You should always include the support.$$f_X(x)= 2(1-x)~\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}$$

Comment: Ah, I see. So to derive the cumulative density function for $X$ we would simply integrate respect to $x$ from 0 to $x$ then?